# Standard ML Binary Tree

Tags: smlnj, ml, sml

I am still having problems with this so I can going to ask for more help.

We are given:

```
datatype which = STRING of string | INT of int
```

Part 1. We are told we need to created another datatype named whichTree for a binary tree containing the values of type "which" where data is only at the leaves of the tree.

I assumed this would be the correct answer:

```
datatype whichTree = Empty | Leaf of which | Node of whichTree*whichTree;
```

It turns out it is not as when I run:

```
val inttree = Node(Leaf(1), Leaf(2));
```

I get an error.

I was able to figure out that I can do something like this:

```
datatype 'a whichTree = Empty | Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a whichTree * 'a whichTree;
```

or

```
datatype whichTree = Empty | Leaf of int | Node of whichTree*whichTree;
```

But neither of these seem correct to me as in my first case my datatype name has a 'a in it and in my other one I am saying Leaf of int when I should be able to specify string or int by using which.

Can anyone tell me what the correct answer it or provide me with some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `whichTree` is correct, you're just missing the constructor for `which` in your `inttree`:

```
val inttree = Node(Leaf(INT 1), Leaf(INT 2))
```